# Differential equations - Hypergeometric function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

I would like to solve the equation $(x^2-x-6)y''+(5+3x)y'+y=0$ at $x=3$. I think we have to solve this problem in considering the Gauss's hypergeometric equation on the form **(*)** $$x(1-x)y''+[c-(a+b+1)x]y'-aby=0.$$

Does someone could solve the problem or just tell me how I can bring the original equation as **(*)**?

The general case is $$(x-A)(x-B)y''+(C+Dx)y'+Ey=0.$$

This equation can be transformed into hypergeometric equation through the change of variables: $t=\frac{x-A}{B-A}$ and obtain that : $t(t − 1)y'' + (F + Gt)y' + Hy = 0$...But how could solve this equation?