# $25 w(w-1)y''+(14-15w)y'+y=0$ - Gauss's Hypergeometric equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

I would like to solve the equation $(x^2-x-6)y''+(5+3x)y'+y=0$ near the singular point $x=3$. I think we have to solve this problem in considering the Gauss's hypergeometric equation on the form $$x(1-x)y''+[c-(a+b+1)x]y'-aby=0.$$

I got $t(t-(-5))y''+(14+3t)y'+y=0$ with the change of variable $t=(x-3)$. Thereafter, with the appropriate change of variable $w=\frac{t-A}{B-A}=\frac{t}{-5}$, I obtain $25 w(w-1)y''+(14-15w)y'+y=0$, but how could solve this equation?

Comment: How odd that the exact same question was posted just an hour ago by a different user: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757974/differential-geometry-hypergeometric-function.

Comment: Observe correctly, the question is a bit different

Comment: Differential **Geometry?**

Comment: The solutions of the Gauss hypergeometric differential equation are called Gauss hypergeometric functions (who would have guessed?), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation . For more information on hypergeometric functions, including expressions for specific values of the parameters, see http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/.

Comment: @FritsVeerman Would you be able to give me the complete solution?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not going to do that. See @Moo's earlier remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Transform the equation to:

$w(1-w)y''+(- \frac{14}{25} -(-\frac{15}{25})w )y'-\frac{1}{25}y=0$

then solve the equation system:

$\begin{array}{lcl}
a+b+1 & = & -\frac{15}{25} \\
a\cdot b & = & \frac{1}{25}
\end{array}$

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to find a linear transformation of $x$ (combined with a rescaling of $y$) such that the quadratic in front of the second derivative, $x^2 -x-6$, is transformed to the form $x(1-x)$. The key is to compare the roots of both parabolas. Your parabola has roots at $x=-2$ and $x=3$, whereas $x(1-x)$ has roots at $0$ and $1$. So, it would suffice to first shift 'your' parabola $2$ to the right, such that its roots are $x=0$ and $x=5$, and then divide $x$ by $5$ to obtain the desired roots. In other words, you can introduce
\begin{equation}
 \xi = \frac{x+2}{5},
\end{equation}
and write $y(x) = \eta(\xi)$.